# How can we stop this security hole in PVOB?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Any user can run this command and blow out the vob-registry in the PVOB.

```
cleartool unregister -view -uuid c8b329ed.60814357.9806.26:55:85:75:e2:bf
```

I believe triggers won't work in this case.

Is there any solution to restrict user to use those command?

Comment: this is a command for the vob: cleartool unregister -vob -uuid d6ca911d.229a41bb.942b.fd:ed:f2:bb:5c:f8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even unregistered, you can still re-register a vob with [`cleartool register`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_register.htm), so it isn't too bad.

```
cleartool register -vob -host corona -hpath /vobstg/tests.vbs –gpath /net/corona/vobstg/test.vbs /vobstg/test.vbs
```

Comment: For the command you provided, admin involvement required but to unregister, anyone can do it.